# Repeat array item in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I have an array of array of strings.

I want to repeat the `"x"` x times.

I do not want it to be in one string, like what happens using `strings.Repeat()`. I need it to be individual array items. Is that possible?

```
[]string{"x", "x", "x"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
count := 10
strings.Split(strings.Repeat("x", count), "")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zi0RqNT9lm9

or simply

```
func sliceFilledWithString(size int, str string) []string {
    data := make([]string, size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        data[i] = str
    }
    return data
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TR99bdH8ewX

Comment: If you want to repeat a string more than 1 character long, the first method won't work.  Also the second method is a bit faster in general.

Answer (score 1):

With generics you can write a more general function.  (Maybe something like this will be added to std lib.)

```
func sliceRepeat[T any](size int, v T) []T {
    retval := make([]T, 0, size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        retval = append(retval, v)
    }
    return retval
}
```

https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/5TIJRFNQPUY